# How to insert data into a table such that one value comes from another table and other value comes from the form

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

i am insert data into a table such that one value comes from another table and other value comes from the form.

```
select 
  SNO,bill_num,item_type,size,article_num,ind_num
  ,colour,amount,all_comment,vendor_name,incoice_no
   ,Bill_Date,Receiving_Date,color_name,MRP,unique_bill_id 
 into @tid 
from DEMO_STOCK_TABLE_KP 
where sno='"+ uni_s+"';
@did=d;

insert into SOLD_items_RETAILX 
  (SNO,bill_num,item_type,size,article_num
  ,ind_num,colour,amount,all_comment,vendor_name
  ,incoice_no,Bill_Date,Receiving_Date,color_name
  ,MRP,unique_bill_id,gst_bill_no) values (@tid,@did);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a general case, if you want to do an `INSERT` with a mix of values from a table and another source like a literal, you can do an `INSERT/SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT src_col1, src_col2, 'some_literal'
FROM MyTable
```

So, maybe you can do something similar here:

```sql
insert into SOLD_items_RETAILX (
  SNO, bill_num, item_type, size, article_num, ind_num, colour, 
  amount, all_comment, vendor_name, incoice_no, Bill_Date, Receiving_Date,
  color_name, MRP, unique_bill_id, gst_bill_no)
select 
  SNO, bill_num, item_type, size, article_num, ind_num, colour, 
  amount, all_comment, vendor_name, incoice_no, Bill_Date, Receiving_Date,
  color_name, MRP, unique_bill_id, <gst_bill_no> 
from DEMO_STOCK_TABLE_KP 
where sno='"+ uni_s+"';
```

You'd just have to replace the `<gest_bill_no>` placeholder with the correct value.